# email client on mobile ubuntu

Tags: software-installation, ubuntu-touch

I have bought a bq Aquaris E5 ubuntu edition cellphone
now I found that there is no e-mail client installed (only or G-mail)
I could to find a suitable application on the Ubuntu Store
I would like to install the ANJAL e mail client (mobile evolution version)
can anybody tell me howw to do this, because the Ubuntu Store does not 
show it

Answer (score 5):

In order to install an application on the phone it has to be specifically compiled for Ubuntu Touch, so this ANJAL client (which is not for mobile but for netbooks from what I've read) won't work here.

So far the only native email client for Ubuntu Touch (though still in beta) is Dekko - https://uappexplorer.com/app/dekko.dekkoproject and you can install it from the app store.